# Transform Shapefile from WGS84 to NAD83 using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wgs84, state-plane, nad83

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reproject a vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/how-to-reproject-a-vector-layer-in-qgis)

I have some shapefiles whose CRS is WGS 1984 and I have some shapefiles whose CRS is NAD 1983 State Plane Illinois East. I want them all to have the latter CRS (IL State Plane.) It is my understanding that I will need to transform the datum of the WGS84 shapefiles? Is there a way to do this using QGIS or other free software? Thanks!

Comment: This may be a duplicate question.  See [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/35590/7424)

Answer (score 1):

Open your file in QGIS, right click the layer and Save As...

In the section labeled CRS click Browse.  In the new window you can search for your desired CRS.  Save your file and it will now assign the projection to your shapefile.
Search didn't work, at least for me, in some earlier version of QGIS, but NAD83/Illinois East is under *Projected Coord System > Transverse Mercator > NAD83 Illinois East* it has the EPSG of 26971.  There is a projection with the US-ft units, but don't use that... it is just weird and most people will expect it to be in metres.

QGIS will take care of assigning the new datum, projection, and ellipsoid.

Comment: be sure to add the outputted file to your qgis map to check to see if it worked. Then check the prj file to be absolutely sure.