# Why does Points in polygon create empty PNTCNT column from OSM points?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I tried to use the Points in polygon tool in qgis 2.2.0 and it worked fine as long as I used my own points.

When I tried to 'count' the points generated from OSM layers both from dowloaded shapefiles from geofabrik - here I thought the problem is with the projection which is tricky to fix-, but then I downloaded the same points from the OpenLayers plugin with Vector > OpenStreetMap > Dowload data.

The result is the same. I generate the output grid layer but the PNTCNT coulmn is totally empty. Do you have any idea why? I am all new to qgis and these kinds of operations in general, so please explain me what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Which CRS is the polygon data in? Did you reproject the OSM points to the polygon CRS? Note that on-the-fly reprojection is insufficient.

Comment: that could be the problem... I have 'on the fly' CRS transformation enabled and I set it at the project properties to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator as I read that it is required to show OSM data without distorsion. My polygon is also in WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. I also tried to change it to simple WGS 84 as the points are in that, but then they all 'disappear'.. so how do I reproject the points to the polygon CRS?

Comment: It is incorrect that OSM vector data requires Pseudo Mercator. This only applies to the prerendered raster tiles of OSM, Googlemaps and others. OSM vector data is provided in WGS84 EPSG:4326.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most spatial analysis tools to work, all layers have to be in the same CRS. Note that **on-the-fly reprojection is insufficient**.

If you need help on how to reproject vector data see:
[Reprojecting vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/how-to-reproject-a-vector-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: Thank you! I reprojected the polygon and now it works fine! Now everything is in WGS84, however at the project preferences I still need to leave Pseudo Mercator otherwise everything is distorted. Anyhow, that is the next step to me to understand...