# Projecting Austria data with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, austria

I'm trying to reproject [this](http://www.statistik.at/web_de/downloads/geodaten/statistik_austria_siedlungseinheiten_polygon_2mio.zip) dataset from [Austria Statistik Geodata](http://www.statistik.at/web_en/classifications/regional_breakdown/locality/index.html).

Data comes in "MGI_Austria_Lambert", and I'm trying to reproject to WGS84

What I'm doing is Saving layer as... and selecting EPSG:4326, but the layer is still in the same place.

The other option i'm trying is changing the original .prj file with other one from a layer in EPSG:4326, but I have the same result.

I don't what can I do to solve it.

I've also tried setting the projection with:Set SRC to layer, and selecting 4326, but no changes.

Comment: Finally solved it with Kurt's suggestion, that was the same I was doing before, but finally worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the instructions I gave here [Reprojecting vector layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/how-to-reproject-a-vector-layer-in-qgis/35595#35595) and you are done:

before:
[image]

and after:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried this out and had no issues... once the data was re-projected and added to the map, I re-set the map to EPSG:3857, added the Google map via OpenLayers, and the re-projected (and projected on the fly) dataset of yours worked just fine:

[image]