# Retrieve Google Maps API friendly latitudes and longitudes from shapefile polygon

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a shapefile with a polygon in it, and I am trying to the latitudes and longitudes associated with it so I can use them with the Google Maps API.

So far I have been working with QGIS Lyon and have managed to get some sort of coordinates, but they are not compatible with Google Maps. This is what the coordinates look like in the CSV:

`"shapeid","x","y"
"0.0","543905.4","183199.1"
"0.0","543905.0","183198.9"
...`

I have used a plugin called `MMQGIS` to get the values in the CSV file.

I have also tried to use `Vector->OpenStreetMap->Download Data`, and this does give coordinates in the right format, but the output file is very large, 12MB, and it has around 92k nodes, which is definitely way too many.

I've come to a point where I can't think of anything else and Google isn't being very helpful either (or maybe I'm not doing the right search).

So, it would be very helpful if someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: save your shapefile into a new shapefile with a wgs84 (epsg 4326) projection . this new file will have lat/lon values . see here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/how-to-reproject-a-vector-layer-in-qgis

Comment: @Kurt I've tried this and I'm still not getting the latlngs in the format that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is trying to achieve similar results:

I managed to get the latlngs in the format required by Google Maps API, by following these steps:

1. Select the `Save as...` option after right-clicking on the loaded layer
2. Choose `Keyhole Markup Language [KML]` as the format
3. Set CRS to `EPSG:4326 - WGS 84`