# Saving to KML in QGIS producing bizarre results

Tags: qgis, kml

I have a shapefile in WGS84 [image] and I'm trying to save to a KML. Something is going wrong in this save and my KML file contains all of the polygons stacked in a sort of column shape.

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is not in WGS84.

Your coordinates should be in between -180 and 180, unlike the 200000 seen in the screenshot.

When converting to KML, it will convert it to EPSG:4326.

Comment: Ahh thank you. The layer was in British National grid before but I saved it as WGS84. Do you know why this has not converted the layer?

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/reprojecting-vector-layer-in-qgis

Comment: You could just save directly to KML from British National Grid. It should convert it for you.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto why do you think that KML has anything to do with EPSG:3857? http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html notes that `KML by specification uses only a single projection, EPSG:4326. All OGR KML output will be presented in EPSG:4326`.

Comment: Heikki will probably correct soon what he wrote about EPSG:3857 but the source data must indeed have wrong projection. Compare "I have a shapefile in WGS84" with the first screen capture where QGIS map is in EPSG:4326 and coordinate view shows all too big coordinates. GDAL must know the correct source SRS before it can make convertion into EPSG:4326 for KML. Now it believes that data are already in right system and just writes the big coordinates into KML withour conversion.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto The reproject function wasn't working, it was just producing the same result when run. However your suggestion of saving directly from British National Grid did work. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreJ sorry got my Mercators and pseudo Mercators in KML backwards. I have edited the answer, however the idea was correct. Phil: I'm glad that worked.