# Two layers with same SRs and same coordinates don't overlap

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers

i'm trying to do some analysis on road accidents.

I have :

- a .csv with lat,long data of road accidents
- a .shp with the road
  network

When I create a new layer from .csv, it is automatically assigned to WGS 84 epsg 4326. 
The road networks instead is  WGS 84 32N epsg 32632

The layers overlap when using the different SRs. The problem is when I change them to a uniform SR (that is, when creating a new shp of road accidents with epsg 32632), they don't overlap anymore and can only be visualized one at time.

Any ideas?

I'm using Qgis 2.18 (but the same with Qgis 3.0)

Comment: How did you create new shp? If you only changed from the Set Layer SRS, it will not work as expected.

Comment: The CSV does not have a CRS stored to disk. So it might help to first create a Shapefile with EPSG:4326, then reproject that to EPSG:32632 using a different filename.

Comment: thank you guys
neogeomat, i loaded the csv and then saved the new .shp after having  changed the SR from epsg 4326 to epsg 32632. ..and it suddenly disappears from the radar :-(. Any better solutions
Andrej, i will immediately try

Comment: @neogeomat, the weirdest thing is that they perfectly overlap when referred to two different Srs, they don't when referred to the same (don't know how to post here images to show better the problem)

Comment: @andreJ, tried but nothing changed

Comment: To confirm, you stated "changed the SR from epsg 4326 to epsg 32632" -- did you do this via reproject?  (Menu>Processing>Toolbox (this will open a side window). At processing toolbox search box, type 'reproject layer'. Choose 'reproject layer' -- per [@r01f 51m035](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/reprojecting-vector-layer-in-qgis) )

Comment: @smiller, hey hey it seems to work. finger crossed and thank you thank you for the moment