# Why does my heatmap only give "degrees" as an option?

Tags: coordinate-system, heat-map

I'm trying to create a heatmap of a layer.  I'm not sure what I should set the radius at, but it only gives me "degrees" as an option, instead of meters, feet, or other distance units.  I don't know what degrees refers to, since these are points on a map.  The CRS for these layers is set the same as the project CRS.  What does this error message mean?  [image]

Comment: Please always provide errors as text and not just a picture.  Also, please always mention the GIS software that you are using within the body of your question, and add a tag for it too.

Answer (score 1):

The project's CRS is in geographic coordinates (WGS 84) [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326) and the unit is decimal degree. You need to change the projection of your CRS to the one that uses meter unit, such as UTM, with the correct UTM zone based on where the data is located.

Comment: I changed the project's UTM, but when I change the layer UTM to match it the data set disappears.

Comment: @DanG You need to change the layer CRS not the project CRS using `Save layer as` , check https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35595/63384, and then load the data on a new project, not the existing one.