# QGIS does not change y and x coordinates to decimal degrees

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, decimal-points

I have data for Danish administrative areas. So far I have calculated centroids and added y and x coordinates for them. However, I have not been able to convert them to decimal degrees when exporting as CSV. In the "Save Vector Layer as..." I tried changing the CRS to EPSG:4326 which was what I read would do it. But when I export the CSV, the format is not as such (between -180 and 180 for the y coordinate for example).

I have read several forum posts about this exact issue without result.

Comment: Save to 4326 first, then add coordinates, then export.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you elaborate "Save to 4326 first"? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: To re-project the layer "save to 4326" see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35590/reprojecting-vector-layer-in-qgis Selecting EPSG:4326 as the CRS.

Comment: When you say "I tried changing the CRS to EPSG:4326" how did you do this? I would try re-projecting the data then doing the save.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped!

Answer (score 3):

Use the following expression to (internally) transform a layer in **any CRS** to `EPSG:4326` and from there get lat/lon values - no need to actually reproject as long as you only want to get coordinate values in another CRS than the one the layer is defined in. The variable `@layer_crs` automatically gets the CRS of the layer, so even without knowing what CRS it has, you can use the expression.

This expression is for longitude, for latitude simply replace `x` by `y`:

```
 x (transform( $geometry,  @layer_crs, 'EPSG:4326'))
```

*Layer in `EPSG:32032` (UTM zone 32N), coordinate values calculated in lat/lon, based on `EPSG:4326`. First two columns are in layer's UTM coordinates for comparison:*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Additionally the ["Add X/Y fields to layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-x-y-fields-to-layer) geoalgorithm can be used, where the *'Coordinate reference system to use for the generated x and y fields'* can be specified.

[image: window]